# How to set mysql where clause to go back to id=1 if no higher id exists

Tags: php, mysql

I need somewhere in the code to say "if there is nothing found after the current id, start searching from id `1`". I'm running into the problem where (for example) I'm querying for any id > 4 where status == 1. Because id `5` doesn't have the right status, the code doesn't execute. I need it to go back to id #1.

**mysql table example**

```
-----------------------------------------
|  id  |  page  |  status  |  referral  |
-----------------------------------------
|  1   |  new   |    1     |  new.php   |
|  2   |  used  |    0     |  used.php  |
|  3   |  lease |    1     |  lease.php |
|  4   |  video |    0     |  video.php |
|  5   |  serv  |    0     |  serv.php
-----------------------------------------
```

**php code**

```
<?php 
$referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM allpages 
        WHERE status = '1' && referral != '$referral' && id > '4'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       if ($row['status'] == 1){
          echo "<script>
                  setTimeout(function() {
                     window.location.href = '" . $row['url'] . "';
                  }, 10000);        
                </script>";
         break;
       }else { echo "no page to display"; }
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use prepared statements.

Comment: Adding `limit 1` to your query is a good idea. In addition to that, you'll want to remove the while loop as you are only interested in the first row. So remove the `while` surrounding the `if`, remove the `break` statement, and add `limit 1` to your query, to fix your second problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the first `id` greater than `4` and otherwise return the first `id` in the table. You can do this by ordering by `(id > 4) DESC` and then by `id ASC`. This will ensure all id's `> 4` will appear before id 1. Also remove the `id>4` from your where clause. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM allpages WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY (id > '4') DESC, id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have not thought of this in my answer. Would make it a lot easier. Good Point.

Comment: I found this to be the best answer. Only thing I added was LIMIT 1 at end of query. Thanks so much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the security reason regarding SQL Injectons, you have to understand, if there are no rows given, you have to an other sql request to get data from the beginning

In this case you would need an SQL Like

```
SELECT * FROM allpages WHERE status = '1' && referral != '$referral' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

This will do the job. Keep in mind, the code could be a lot nicer and less, if you use a function to get the sql result.

```
<?php

$referral = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM allpages WHERE status = '1' && referral != '$referral' && id > '4' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
if (!empty($row) && is_array($row)) {
        // result found 
        echo "<script>
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = '" . $row['url'] . "';
            }, 10000);      
          </script>";
} else { 
        // no result yet, start search from beginning
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM allpages WHERE status = '1' && referral != '$referral' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2));
        if (!empty($row2) && is_array($row2)) {
                // result found by start from beginning
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2));
                echo "<script>
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.href = '" . $row2['url'] . "';
                    }, 10000);      
                  </script>";
        } else {
                // noting found from start
                echo "no page to display"; 
        }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: i couldn't get this code to run, tried a few things but page wouldn't load with code on it. I ended up using Max Meijer answer below. I appreciate you taking the time to help though!